# C# - How to get element, that opened ContextMenuStrip in toolStripMenuItem_Click?

Tags: c#

I have `TreeNode` elements with `this.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1` and event, that auto-generated on double click in VS:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

How can I get a `TreeNode` element, that I clicked on with right mouse button? As I see, `EventArgs` have nothing, to receive a "parent" element of `TreeNode`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I deleted my answer. See this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on it is close to what I wrote, but the event is not attached to the TreeNode as I though, but to the ContextStrip. I believe it is a duplicated question

Comment: No, that example for ContextMenuStrip doesn't work for me - I got a null for sourceControl on line `Control sourceControl = owner.SourceControl;`

Comment: Try this instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208944/c-sharp-right-click-on-treeview-nodes

Comment: and one more chance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527/find-node-clicked-under-context-menu